# How to process Action.Submit in nodejs V4 Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to look for an example of processing an adaptive card submit action from V4 nodejs bot. I have looked up [repo examples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/bc644fd8141cfcc6d3cd429353c0abe84de703ef/samples/javascript_nodejs) and all of them have action type Action.OpenUrl. I am trying to find how can I process Action.Submit from AD card and, handle that in waterfall step.

- ],
- "actions": [
- {
- "type": "Action.Submit",
- "title": "Submit this"
- }
- ]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `data` property as part of the `Action.Submit`. The `data` property can be any value. However, how you send the value determines whether it is presented as an `imBack` (visible to the user) or a `postBack` (not visible to the user).

Also, if you are including input fields leading up to the `Action.Submit`, then the data from those fields will be read into the `data` property which can, optionally, be left out. See this [sample](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/) for a demo.

**imBack** - sends the `data` value in the activity  and displays "Submitted" to the user (type: string)

`"data": "Submitted"`

**postBack** - sends the `data` value in the activity but does not display to the user (type: key/value pair)

`"data": { "value": "Submitted" }`

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Present a form and submit it back to the originator"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "firstName",
      "placeholder": "What is your first name?"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "lastName",
      "placeholder": "What is your last name?"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Action.Submit",
      "data": {
        "value": "Submitted"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Hey Steven Kanberg, I was looking for a bot code example to process the Action submit event and, call respective dialog or waterfall step. 

Like, what piece of code I need when user clicks submit button. and, take submitted text box value to a dialog.